# how to automate adb events

Tags: adb, keyevent

I have used various adb shell commands to automate the loading of a URL to a handset via adb. It loads up the page but I need to then select an image on the screen. I have tried adb shell input keyevents but this is sometimes missing the image so I need to use the send event and mimic the touching of the screen.

Can someone please help. How do I find out the co-ordinates of the picture?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`monkeyrunner`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) to get screenshot

```
import sys
import os
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(10 , os.getenv('ANDROID_SERIAL'));
image = device.takeSnapshot();
image.writeToFile("/folder/test.png","png");
```

Don't forget to `SET` on windows and `EXPORT` on Linux `ANDROID_SERIAL`
`ANDROID_SERIAL` - it's your device number (can be obtain by using `adb devices`)

Then open image in `Paint` or any other, and get the coordinates of picture.

Answer (score 0):

Enable `Show pointer location` from developer options. It will show coordinates of the point where you touch. using the coordinates you can touch on required points using monkeyrunner or

```
adb shell input tap <x><y>
```

.